# background animate image is not working in IE and Opera browsers

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer, opera

This is my css code:

```
body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    #slideshow {
        position: relative;
        overflow: hidden;
        height: 100px;
    }
 #fixme
{

    height : 60px;
    position: relative;
    overflow : hidden;
}
    #animate-area { 
        height: 122%;
        width: 2538px;
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: -15px;
        background-image: url('http://s30.postimg.org/qnju89rkx/banner.png') ;
        -ms-animation: animatedBackground 40s linear infinite;
        -moz-animation: animatedBackground 40s linear infinite;
        -webkit-animation: animatedBackground 30s linear infinite;
    }
    /* Put your css in here */
    @keyframes animatedBackground {
        from { left: 0; }
        to { left: -1269px; }
    }
    @-webkit-keyframes animatedBackground {
        from { left: 0; }
        to { left: -1269px; }
    }
    @-moz-keyframes animatedBackground {
        from { left: 0; }
        to { left: -1269px; }
    }
```

Thsi is JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cz04c4nx/8/

Now its working fine in chrome and mozilla browsers, but didn't work animation in IE and Opera.

May i know what is the reason? and how to fix this?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: can anybody help  me please?

Comment: For me your jsfiddle example work great in IE10 and Opera 20.0.1387.91. Have a look at this: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-animation

Comment: Link I provided above tells you for what version of every browser the CSS3 Animation is supported. You can view that only IE10 and higher support the Animation.

Comment: This is what i try to do, but i need your IE and Opera versions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60427/discussion-between-dragos-sandu-and-sasi).

Comment: @DragosSandu: It is working in Opera, but Didn't work in IE, and In Opera works when i run like this, file://localhost/C:/xampp/htdocs/banner/index.html

Comment: Click on the link of my answer above for talk in chat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure, but i think you forget something. Try the code below.
Replace your `#animate-area` div with this:

```
 #animate-area { 
    height: 122%;
    width: 2538px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: -15px;
    background-image: url('http://s30.postimg.org/qnju89rkx/banner.png') ;
    animation: animatedBackground 40s linear infinite;
    -webkit-animation: animatedBackground 30s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: animatedBackground 40s linear infinite;
    -o-animation: animatedBackground 40s linear infinite;
    -ms-animation: animatedBackground 40s linear infinite;  
}
```

Difference is just in animation tag. After that, at the bottom of your CSS add the following.

```
    @-ms-keyframes animatedBackground {
    from { left: 0; }
    to { left: -1269px; }
}

  @-o-keyframes animatedBackground {
    from { left: 0; }
    to { left: -1269px; }
}
```

ANIMATION IN IE8. Copy the following lines in your head section of you website. IF user browser is low than IE10 than the jQuery animation will be load.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--[if lt IE 10]>
<script> 

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#animate-area").animate({left:'-1269px'}, 40000, function() {});
    });
    </script> 
    <![endif]-->
```

It doesn't look exactly like CSS3 Key-frames, but is a little replacement.

Comment: What version of Opera and IE do you have?